# Link for Search Results

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I currently have a job board on my site where users can put in a job title or keyword and a location to search for a job.

The results are displayed using Jquery/AJAX without a page refresh.  However, I'd like to be able to link to the results for a specific search.  For example, if I search for web development positions in OH, I'd like to be able to send a link to someone else who will be able to click on the link and go directly to the page with those results already loaded.

I have some knowledge of PHP but none of Ajax or Javascript/Jquery, which is why this is so hard for me.  I'm hoping someone can help me with this.

Here's the code that is currently displaying the results:

```
  jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
      // search button clicked
      jQuery("input[name='indeedsearchbutton']").click(function () {
          indeedsearchbusy();
          indeedsearchcall();
      })

      // reset page if query changes
      jQuery("input[name='q']").change(function () {
          jQuery("input[name='start']").val(1);
      })

      // reset page if location changes
      jQuery("input[name='l']").change(function () {
          jQuery("input[name='start']").val(1);
      })

      if (autosearch) {
          indeedsearchbusy();
          indeedsearchcall();
      }
  })

  // pagination set start position
  function setstart(s) {
      jQuery("input[name='start']").val(s);
      indeedsearchbusy();
      indeedsearchcall();
  }

  // get json data from inputs for ajax call
  function getdata() {
      var d = {
          action: 'indeedcallback',
          q: (jQuery("input[name='q']").length != 0 ? jQuery("input[name='q']").val() : jQuery("select[name='q']").val()),
          l: jQuery("input[name='l']").val(),
          start: jQuery("input[name='start']").val()
      }
      return d;
  }

  // display json results from ajax call
  function indeeddisplayresults(resultsjson) {
      var rpage = "";
      if (resultsjson.pagination) rpage += resultsjson.pagination;

      if (resultsjson.html) rpage += resultsjson.html;

      if (resultsjson.pagination) rpage += resultsjson.pagination;

      jQuery("div#indeedsearchresults").html(rpage);
  }

  // ajax call to search indeed
  function indeedsearchcall() {
      var data = getdata();
      jQuery.post(wpajaxurl, data, function (response) {
          resultjson = eval("(" + response + ")");
          if (resultjson) {
              indeeddisplayresults(resultjson);
          }
      })
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would just use the URL and some sort of hashbang (GETish) functionality. So each time someone does a search, the URL changes, and each time the page is loaded, it looks at the URL for search parameters and if they exist, runs a search...

There is a nice GIST on this with a full explanation of the code below: https://gist.github.com/miohtama/1570295

```
function parseHashBangArgs(aURL) {

aURL = aURL || window.location.href;

var vars = {};
var hashes = aURL.slice(aURL.indexOf('#') + 1).split('&');

for(var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++) {
   var hash = hashes[i].split('=');

   if(hash.length > 1) {
       vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
   } else {
      vars[hash[0]] = null;
   }      
}

return vars;
```

}

OK in reference to your question for HOW to use this: I have made a working example (code below), but you will have to implement in your own code (I cant do literally everything for you)...

```
<input id="searchBar" type="text" value="enter search here" /><br />
<input id="theButton" type="button" name="" value="getHash" /><br />
Hash value is: <a id="hashValue"></a>

jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $('#searchBar').change(function() {
        search(document.getElementById('searchBar').value)
    });
    $('#theButton').click(function() {
        getHash();
    });
})
function search(searchTerms){
    location.hash = "searchTerm="+searchTerms;   
}

function getHash(){
    var hashObj= new Object(); 
    hashObj=(parseHashBangArgs())
    document.getElementById('hashValue').innerHTML=hashObj.searchTerm;
}

function parseHashBangArgs(aURL) {
... code from GIST above...
```

Comment: I've actually seen this before, but the problem is I have no idea how to implement it.  I have never worked with anything like this before; the code above is from a free WordPress plugin I'm using.  Is there any way you can help me out?  Thanks!

Comment: I don't think this will work.  There is a PHP file that uses cURL to get information and it uses a whole bunch of other data.  I'm just really confused. Sorry

Comment: But the example works lol... If you can't figure it out for some reason, that means you have another question. Not that my answer is wrong...